# how to implement mount function in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, mount

I,m suppose to write a client/server program which mount a directory from the server into client hierarchy. What I have to do is, instead of using linux mount function, implement a method in c.c++ that works like mount function. I did a lot of googling on the net but can't find any good tutorial or document that could help. I will be  very grateful if you help me and give me some advice, suggestion or introduce a tutorial/document as a starting point.

Comment: Why can't you use the tools provided to you by the OS?

Comment: All of the source code should be available, which part did you get stuck with?

Comment: Why do you think that reinventing `mount(2)` is the way to do this?

Comment: Do you really want to reimplement mount, or just create something completely different that only looks similar? :) For example, if you want to simulate file system on client that delegates all operations to the real file system on the server, you can use already existing network filesystems (NFS, CIFS, …) or implement your own using FUSE.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's a university project and we have to do in this way

Comment: @Messa I know about NFS and other network file systems, but we are suppose to build a simple network file system and virtual file system. as I mentioned it's a university project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. If this is an assignment, it could be about several things:

- Implementing a filesystem ([FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) would probably be the simplest place to start).
- Just emulating the calls, and defining your own e.g. `ls`, `cd` etc. for educational purposes, and bringing in the data from the server.
- Implementing a tool like `mount`, possibly using the [`mount()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/mount.htm) system call.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I think I have to implement a new simple file system and use mount system call. but I have to mount a remote folder.